# does the load event fire when SVG is loaded as src for an img element?

Tags: javascript, svg

In this file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
   version="1.1"
   id="svg2"
   height="40.2271"
   width="25.1">
  <rect
     style="fill:red"
     id="rect44"
     width="12.625"
     height="14.5"
     x="6.3289919"
     y="4.5130124" />
</svg>
```

the load event fires when the file is loaded as a standalone, bur when loaded as an image here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2//EN">
<html>
<head>
  <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
  <img src="marker_so.svg">
</body>
</html>
```

it doesn't fire anymore.

Why is that? and is there a way to have the event fire *inside* the SVG file when loaded as an image?

In my case, I am trying to fire a function that changes some colors inside the SVG file based on the URL it got loaded from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

listen image load event in SVG:

```
<image xlink:href="example.png" width="10" height="10" 
       onload="alert('loaded')"/>

<script>
  var img = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "image");
  img.addEventListener('load', function() { alert('loaded'); });
  // or alternatively:
  // img.onload = function() { alert('loaded'); }
  img.width.baseVal.value = 100;
  img.height.baseVal.value = 100;
  img.href.baseVal = "example.png";
</script>
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/ZXdxc/81/

Comment: no, I want the onload event to fire when the SVG is loaded as a part of an img src request, and it doesn't seem to happen

Comment: I updated my answer. Maybe it example will help you